# EventEmitter.emit() is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9, eventemitter, primeng-dropdowns

I have a child component where I use a dropdown from primeng plug in to send its value to the parent whenever the user changes the selection. I use the *EventEmitter.emit()* function to emit a value of type Solution. The *Solution* is an interface defined by me.   
Here is how I defined the emitter:

```
@Output('solutionChange') selectedSolution: EventEmitter<Solution> = new EventEmitter<Solution>();
```

Here is how I called the emitter:

```
public onSolutionChange(args) {
    let solution: Solution = args.value as Solution;
    this.selectedSolution.emit(solution);
  }
```

**The problem** is when I call the **emit()** function it gives the error **TypeError: emit is not a function**.

I already tried to change the definition of the emitter to `@Output('solutionChange') selectedSolution: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();` because the **args.value** is an any type coming from backend, but still the same error. I also tried replacing the emit() function with the next() function.

Comment: Show exactly how are you are importing `EventEmitter`.

Comment: You want to import the Angular/core/      eventemitter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. I tried to solve it for about an hour and when I thought I got no other options I decided to ask for help. It was my mistake because I wasn't careful at the parameter I gave in NgModel, on the HTML, and I also used the wrong parameter in the service that gets the data from backend. I also checked the types many times before I asked the question.
The reason why I keep this question is to help other guys that might do the same mistake like I did.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Likely you are importing the wrong `EventEmitter`, which can happen automatically in IDE such as VS Code. It tries to import Node.js `events` [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) make sure you import from `@angular/core` [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) like:

```
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I used that import. Thanks

Comment: No, it didn't. I used the import you suggested me, but it was an other problem. Thanks for your help!